# Carrierwave callback after all versions are created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, sidekiq

In my Rails app, I would like to update my database once all versions of an uploaded image are created and stored.  Is there a callback that ensures that recreate_versions! is complete?

Background:
I allow users to rotate images that they upload to my site. I show a preview of the rotation using webkit-transform and only actually rotate the image using imagemagick when the user saves the image.  However, to prevent holding up the app until the image versioning is complete, I do this in a background task and continue to apply the rotation by applying the webkit-transform.  I need to know when the image has been fully rotated before I pull the correct image from the database (rather than rotate the image on the client side).

P.S. I looked at this page: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-use-callbacks, but I also saw that these callbacks are called after ever version, not after all versioning is complete.

Comment: did you get answer for this question? If so can you please share?

Comment: I never got a response, but I believe it's actually a function of using sidekiq to perform the versioning in a background task.  Sidekiq doesn't have anything built in to let you know when a task is complete, but there are gems for doing that like sidekiq status: https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status.  I haven't had a chance to implement the changes yet, but that's the direction I was going to start with.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by using after_save callback, may be this will help you too

```
  after_save :update_avatar_url

  def update_avatar_url
     update_column(:avatar, avatar.thumb.url)   
  end
```

update_column does not trigger after_save callback thus there is no infinite recursion.